# DENY insert,update,delete to user (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I wonder if Postgres support the `DENY` command. I search in the documentation but I couldn't find anything about deny.

I have `GRANT ALL ON table1 TO user1 WITH GRANT OPTION` 
but I don't want user1 to be able to grant insert/update/delete to user2.
(He can do whatever he want with everyone else!!!)

I want to use this command `DENY INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON table1 TO user2;`

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think you need to grant each privilege separately. `grant select on table1 to user1 with grant option; grant insert,update,delete on table1 to user1;`

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear enough. 
I want user1 to be able to grant everything he wants to everyone except user2. That's why i am trying to use the `DENY` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not have `DENY` ACLs.

Instead you must `REVOKE` any rights you want them to be missing, leaving only the rights you want.

e.g.

```
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE blah FROM USER fred;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE blah TO USER Fred;
```

Answer (score 0):

> grant everything he wants to everyone except user2

it is will not work, GRANT option or present or not and not have target USER options

Comment: Sry but i can't undestand what you mean, can you rephrase your answer?

Comment: If You GRANT any options for user, You can not restrict for whom he can GRANT

You can restrict WHAT he can GRANT (INSERT, SELECT ... ) but not TO WHOM

Comment: Yes i know. That's why i am trying to use the `DENY`
example:  `DENY INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON table1 TO user2;`
But because postgreSQL, as i can see, doesn't support `DENY` and i am trying to find another way to do that!